# Casting Generic Interface to base type

Tags: vb.net, generics, casting

I'm struggling to get this hierarchy working with generics. The problem is that Items is generic, specified at the inheritance level, therefore I cannot cast back to BaseItem, i.e. casting from SpecialItem(Of ExtraSpecialItem) to IItemHost(Of BaseItem) when SpecialItem inherits BaseGroup, as BaseGroup implements IItemHost.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseItem
    Public Property ItemNameOrSomething As String
End Class

Public Interface IItemHost(Of TItemType As {BaseItem})
    Property Items As BindingList(Of TItemType) '-- No Out parameter allowed :(
End Interface

Public Class BaseGroup(Of TGroup AS {BaseItem})
    Inherits BaseItem
    Implements IItemHost(Of TGroup)

    '-- This is the key property, all BaseGroup implimentors need an Items property of their specific type
    Public Property Items As New BindingList(Of TGroup)() Implements IItemHost(Of TGroup).Items

End Class

Public Class SpecialItem
    Inherits BaseGroup(Of ExtraSpecialItem)

End Class

Public Class ExtraSpecialItem
    Inherits BaseGroup(Of LeafItem)

End Class

Public Class LeafItem
    Inherits BaseItem

End Class
```

For the most part, this all actually works. What I cannot do is:

```
Dim root = New SpecialItem()
root.ItemNameOrSomething = "Testing 1"
root.Items.Add(New ExtraSpecialItem() With {.ItemNameOrSomething = "Testing 2"})

'-- This specifically, no casting options available.
Dim item = CType(root, IItemHost(Of BaseItem))
Dim subItems = item.Items
Dim testing2Text = subItems.First().ItemNameOrSomething '-- = "Testing 2"
```

Comment: Hold on... I might have solved it...

Comment: No I was wrong, I thought that by specifying BaseItem on IItemHost it would work, but it means I'd have to cast an instance of SpecialItem to CType(si, IItemHost(Of ExtraSpecialItem)).Items (to access .Items on this object).

Answer (score 0):

Ok this hasn't exactly solved the problem, but it's a solution I'm willing to settle with for now.

If I change my BaseItem to have a "BaseItems" collection, my inherited BaseGroup classes can have a default Items IEnumerable. If I need to write back to this collection, I can simply use BaseItems. For standard looping through the items, I can use Items and this will give me the proper casting.

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseItem

    Public Property ItemNameOrSomething As String
    Public Property BaseItems As New BindingList(Of BaseItem)()

End Class

Public Class BaseGroup(Of TGroup As {BaseItem})
    Inherits BaseItem

    Public ReadOnly Property Items As IEnumerable(Of TGroup)
        Get
            Return BaseItems.Cast(Of TGroup)()
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: As a further sidenote, if you're using anything like Infragistics Grids to bind the Items property (especially if it's heavily hierarchical, which it clearly is) then use a BindingList(Of TGroup) as opposed to IEnumerable. I'm using a cached BindingList which is refreshed when the BaseItems.ListChanged is fired.